# Can a KNN regressor predict values outside the range of y?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, knn

So I'm a little new to KNN and ML, but I'm wondering if the KNN regression algorithm can predict y values outside its range. From my understanding, at its most basic, the algorithm takes an average of the k nearest neighbors for regression.

So if I'm predicting stock prices and there is a new all time high, then there would be no neighbor above it, thus it wouldn't be able to accurately predict. I know SK-Learn has a bunch of algorithms and I'm wondering if any of these can be used to predict outside the training set range?

Also for more info this is for multivariate time series forecasting.

I've looked a little in ball tree and kd tree, but haven't found any answers to this questions.
Here's my current code that uses hyperparameter tuning with optuna:

```
 params = {}
    params["n_neighbors"] = trial.suggest_int('n_neighbors', 3, 100)
    params["weights"] = trial.suggest_categorical('weights', ['uniform', 'distance'])
    params["algorithm"] = trial.suggest_categorical('algorithm', ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute'])
    params["leaf_size"] = trial.suggest_int('leaf_size', 5, 100)

    
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor(**params)

    model = knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = model.predict(X_test)
    mae = sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)
    return mae
```

Comment: It will predict for _any_ input values, sure. The question is, should you? Supervised learning algorithms only 'know' about their training data. Extrapolation is always a leap into the unknown.